# Why sometimes do I have EXC_BAD_ACCESS when called from DIspatchQueue?

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

In following code:

```
class DispatchQueuer: DispatchQueuerable {
    private let queue: DispatchQueue

    // MARK: - Initialization

    init(queue: DispatchQueue) {
        self.queue = queue
    }
    func asyncBackground(block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue(label: "", qos: .background).async {
            block() //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        }
    }
}
```

Why it happens?

I use it the following way:

```
    private let dispatchQueuer: DispatchQueuerable
    dispatchQueuer.asyncBackground { [weak self] in
        self?.setupTags()
        self?.setupSuppliers()
        self?.dispatchQueuer.asyncMain {
            completion?()
        }
    }
```

Comment: `DispatchQueuer` doesn't really seem to do anything, at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have data race issues. The problem is partly that every call to `asyncBackground` is on a new queue, so you rapidly have multiple colliding queues and colliding accesses. You should turn your queue into a singleton queue. That way at least you will have the benefit of a serial queue, which at present you are throwing away.

Note that you declare `self.queue` as an instance property. That's a good idea to some extent, but then you never use it! You throw that away too. Personally I would use `static let` to get a true singleton serial queue, and I would *use* it.

Even then, that won't make your accesses thread-safe. But it will be a lot better than what you're doing now.

Comment: I don't say "should" about anything. I'm just pointing out that your use of `DispatchQueue(label: "", qos: .background).async` means that every single time your `asyncBackground` is called, you are creating a totally new and unrelated queue.

Comment: By the way, you might want to run your code with the Thread Sanitizer turned on. If I'm write, it will catch the race condition. If I'm wrong, then the problem lies elsewhere (in memory management?) and you might have to turn on Zombies instead.